# GPU Panic cpp 143 macOS Sierra 10.12.5 stability issues and spontaneous restarts

Tags: macos, kernel-panic

I have no idea what is going on. Any similar experiences or ideas?

Hardware

MacBookPro6,2, 15-inch, Mid 2010
2,53 GHz Intel Core i5
4 GB 1067 MHz DDR3

```
    Kernel Panic
Anonymous UUID:       A0E48994-955D-B364-3818-9F9A63B79B31

Mon May 29 17:53:49 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f9dc4080b): "GPU Panic: mux-regs 5 3 7f 0 0 0 severity 3 switch-state 0 EG power-state 0 3D 0 HDA 0 : \n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.14.47/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:143
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80b378aa90 : 0xffffff801a6ea53c 
0xffffff80b378ab10 : 0xffffff7f9dc4080b 
0xffffff80b378ab80 : 0xffffff7f9b4e22fd 
0xffffff80b378ac40 : 0xffffff7f9b5ae076 
0xffffff80b378ac80 : 0xffffff7f9b5ae0e1 
0xffffff80b378ad00 : 0xffffff7f9b8297f0 
0xffffff80b378ae20 : 0xffffff7f9b5cfbe1 
0xffffff80b378ae40 : 0xffffff7f9b4e8ef4 
0xffffff80b378aef0 : 0xffffff7f9b4e6930 
0xffffff80b378b0e0 : 0xffffff7f9b4e836d 
0xffffff80b378b1b0 : 0xffffff7f9d19d874 
0xffffff80b378b300 : 0xffffff7f9d192819 
0xffffff80b378b650 : 0xffffff7f9d14709e 
0xffffff80b378b690 : 0xffffff7f9d19744a 
0xffffff80b378b710 : 0xffffff7f9d197062 
0xffffff80b378b790 : 0xffffff7f9d17f4e7 
0xffffff80b378b7f0 : 0xffffff7f9d17fdd8 
0xffffff80b378b840 : 0xffffff7f9d18024a 
0xffffff80b378b8a0 : 0xffffff7f9d180970 
0xffffff80b378b8e0 : 0xffffff7f9d14e123 
0xffffff80b378ba60 : 0xffffff7f9d14caa1 
0xffffff80b378bac0 : 0xffffff801ace52ae 
0xffffff80b378bb20 : 0xffffff801ace34b8 
0xffffff80b378bb80 : 0xffffff801acec391 
0xffffff80b378bcc0 : 0xffffff801a7be2f8 
0xffffff80b378bdd0 : 0xffffff801a6ef7bc 
0xffffff80b378be30 : 0xffffff801a6cbfb1 
0xffffff80b378be80 : 0xffffff801a6e0777 
0xffffff80b378bf10 : 0xffffff801a7eb1d8 
0xffffff80b378bfb0 : 0xffffff801a69bdb6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.14.47)[DBE65257-9360-3ACC-9AAC-2AA340DFA59E]@0xffffff7f9dc31000->0xffffff7f9dc45fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.14.47)[E4846CE5-E177-38EE-A979-ECE8409B957D]@0xffffff7f9dc29000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4F7FB6AD-2498-3F71-827C-ED7AA4BF2511]@0xffffff7f9b2f2000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BD9FCDEF-30CB-3911-B247-EE51DD069C76]@0xffffff7f9af32000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(515.3)[A423518D-758D-3021-A111-A59F44D760A8]@0xffffff7f9b439000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[9D276DD1-4746-3504-A9D1-DA189588734D]@0xffffff7f9dc2c000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.2)[C9A3682D-9EE9-3570-B8D9-2F1AE0F332F7]@0xffffff7f9b491000->0xffffff7f9b6f9fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BD9FCDEF-30CB-3911-B247-EE51DD069C76]@0xffffff7f9af32000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(516.1)[480556A8-289E-3A63-83F8-0E9224255A68]@0xffffff7f9b481000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(515.3)[A423518D-758D-3021-A111-A59F44D760A8]@0xffffff7f9b439000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(10.0.2)[51B677B0-3288-360A-B0E7-213640716598]@0xffffff7f9b705000->0xffffff7f9b9adfff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.2)[C9A3682D-9EE9-3570-B8D9-2F1AE0F332F7]@0xffffff7f9b491000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BD9FCDEF-30CB-3911-B247-EE51DD069C76]@0xffffff7f9af32000
         com.apple.GeForceTesla(10.0.2)[EFF5444F-14C9-3FAB-A71B-28097A0B0883]@0xffffff7f9d13b000->0xffffff7f9d201fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BD9FCDEF-30CB-3911-B247-EE51DD069C76]@0xffffff7f9af32000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(516.1)[480556A8-289E-3A63-83F8-0E9224255A68]@0xffffff7f9b481000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(515.3)[A423518D-758D-3021-A111-A59F44D760A8]@0xffffff7f9b439000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.2)[C9A3682D-9EE9-3570-B8D9-2F1AE0F332F7]@0xffffff7f9b491000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
16F73

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0: Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FB2170A8-257D-3C64-B14D-BC06CC94E34C
Kernel slide:     0x000000001a400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801a600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801a500000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 10402282635150
last loaded kext at 4669143207437: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9de55000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 4879406226373: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub  900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f9de2b000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.kaspersky.kext.mark.1.0.6   1.0.6
com.kaspersky.kext.kimul.46 46
com.adguard.nfext   5
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    6.0.5
com.kaspersky.nke   2.3.0a7
com.kaspersky.kext.klif 3.4.5a34
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.17
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   279.48
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.4f18
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   279.48
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.14.47
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.3.1
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.50.19
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 404.50.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  252
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 252
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  341.2
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  394.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  295.20.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.10
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  326.60.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 219.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   172
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   219.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.14.47
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 279.48
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   159.7
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.2
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 279.48
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 279.48
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.15
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.14.47
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   516.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    515.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 5.0.4f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   5.0.4f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.4f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.4f18
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    540.30.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   394.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  131.60.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 258
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  394.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   266.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444.50.16
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B17, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2,53 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533654465238432D47372020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533654465238432D47372020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.4f18, 3 services, 17 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: INTEL SSDSC2BW120H6, 120,03 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Built-in iSight
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: Sounds like the NVidia GPU problem - there was a free recall on those models, but it ended last year - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203554

Comment: So 10.12.5 or El Capitan? Because 10.12 is Sierra, El Cap goes only to 10.11.6.

Answer (score 7):

This was a known issue for this model MacBook Pro. Unfortunately, coverage for this has now ended.

However, there are a few things you can do to minimise the problem.

**gfxCardStatus**

Many users have found that using [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io/) will reduce these issues most of the time. My experience with many users is that versions 1.8.1 and 2.1 seem to be the best for your particular model MBP, even though more recent versions fixed a number of bugs.

So, I’d like you to give [version 1.8.1](https://gfx.io/downloads/gfxCardStatus-1.8.1.zip) a go for a while and see how you go. If you’re not happy with that, then try [version 2.1](https://gfx.io/downloads/gfxCardStatus-2.1.zip) instead.

NOTE: Unfortunately, there were two distinct issues that affected your particular model of MBP. gfxCardStatus was designed to address a hardware problem that occurs on a number of models, including yours. However, your model was also prone to being affected by a software issue that was unique to your model. If your model is affected by that as well, then [version 2.3](http://gfx.io/downloads/gfxCardStatus-2.3.zip) may be a better choice.  So, in summary, I would start with 1.8.1 and see how you go. If you’re not happy, then try 2.1. Then go to 2.3 if you're still not satisfied. **Do not try any other versions for your model MBP!**

**Google Chrome**

If you use Google Chrome I would strongly consider not doing so. However, if you need to, there’s actually a setting in Google Chrome that may help you:

1. Go to Chrome > Preferences
2. Scroll down to the bottom
3. Click on *Show advanced settings…*
4. Scroll down to the *System* heading
5. Uncheck the *Use hardware acceleration when available* option

**Adobe Photoshop**

If you use Adobe Photoshop, you may be able to tinker with Photoshop’s settings as well. Depending on the version you use, if you go to Photoshop’s Preferences and look under the Performance category, there should be a section for GPU Settings. By going into its Advanced Settings you may be able to try different options for the mode of use. It will probably default to Normal, but you could change it to Basic and see whether Photoshop plays more nicely with your MBP. Under GPU settings you could also switch off OpenGL Drawing altogether, but that may limit some functionality.

**Mac OS El Capitan**

There are a couple of things you can do within El Capitan:

- You’re probably already aware of this one – but for your MBP you should have an additional setting under System Preferences > Energy Saver for Automatic graphics switching. Playing with this and the other Graphics option (for better battery life) may be useful.
- Now this one is not so obvious:

  1. Go to System Preferences
  2. Click on Accessibility
  3. Select Display (in the left-hand column)
  4. Tick the Reduce transparency box (on the right-hand side)
  5. Exit System Preferences

Basically, to draw/display transparency in the GUI (windows etc) it needs a lot of graphics power. Not a good idea for your MBP I’m afraid.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same model with the same issues.

I've come across what aims to be a permanent fix instead of the gfxCardStatus work arounds.

The work arounds themselves seem to work ok for the average user, where most people suggest to install gfxCardStatus, and then use "Integrated Only" option, so that it can't actually switch back and forth from the 'discrete' Nvidia GT 330M graphics card, (which is causing the kernel panics and graphics glitches). This works well for those that can handle the basic ~220mb graphics, and that don't need to connect to an external monitor (as the better graphics card Nvidia GT 330M, is what controls the external monitors).

However, I'm one of the people that needs the most from the graphics card and needs to connect to an external monitor occasionally. So.. I've come across the solution from Louis Rossmann and associates..

For yours/mine's particular MBP models' issue (in the mid 2010 15" MBP), the motherboard repair guru Louis Rossmann and associates have discovered that the problem with this exact model only is that there's a $2.50 capacitor that goes faulty, and causes random power shortages to the graphics card. Which is actually what is causing the issues, not the graphics card itself!

I have the same MBP 2010 15" model, and have just ordered the replacement capacitors myself. From what I've read, almost everyone who does this mod completely fixes the issues with the graphics card kernel panics and other issues with the screen glitches etc, and when it switches to the 'discrete' graphics card (Nvidia GT 330M).

Here's the link to his youtube video on replacing the capacitor on the motherboard..
Should you trust an Apple Genius when they tell you it's a graphics processor? 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzcgT_fiVTA&feature=youtu.be

There's also forum posts on the subject, which state which exact capacitors to buy. Of the 3 choices, people were having some issues with the 'ceramic' smaller capacitors, but pretty much 100% success with the 'aluminium' ones.

The aluminium one most people are using with great success is the: "Panasonic EEF-CX0D331R". 
This is the Canadian link I was given, to the exact aluminium one I bought (but I bought from an Australian supplier, stock coming from UK):
https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/EEF-CX0 D331R/PCE4275CT-ND/816445

Hope that helps some of you. This is MacBook Pro 2010 15" only. 
(exact same capacitor issues but in a different location on 2008-9 MBP).

PS: I still think there is 'something' different about Mac OSX Sierra, as I hadn't had these problems for a VERY long time, and now they're back every day, worse than ever, since installing Mac OSX Sierra. Seems to have popped up with MANY other people since upgrading to Sierra.

Comment: Hi R-J-K, that sounds like a good fix, but not as good since already having it fixed, with sierra the issue comes back... I have a 15 inch 2013 MBP and having the exact same issue, same line of code. Did you find a solution to the new problem and does it work also with 2013 model? Thanks!